# FFMPEG "Invalid data found when processing input" MP4 to MP3

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have a question. I'm converting videos from youtube to mp3. From 1000 files around 150 files this message is in the log.

> /home/desktop/www/tmp/314629.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

The thing is it's only about 10% of the conversions. How can i solve this issue?

I'm converting like this

```
ffmpeg -y -i /home/desktop/www/tmp/'.$random_flv_name.'.'.$download_format.' -vn -map_metadata -1 -ab 192k /home/desktop/www/audio/'.$yt_video_id.'/songtitle.mp3
```

Comment: Have/Can you check the integrity of the .mp4 file before attempting to encode?

Comment: Is the output okay?  FFmpeg will often tell you this, but will produce a file just fine.  There probably isn't anything you can do about this, it's likely that the source files are not fully up to spec.